# Validity of \def in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations, variable, def

The following code does not resolve the defines inside tikzpicture and thus does not print the labels.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{article}

\usepackage{keycommand} 
\usepackage{ifthen} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \randomint { m m }
{ \int_rand:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \randomfloat { O{2} m m }
{
    \fp_eval:n { round( (#3-#2)*(rand()/#3) + #2, #1 ) }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\bettersquareroot}{O{2}m}{%
    \fpeval{round(sqrt(#2),#1)}%
}


\newkeycommand\triangleSAS[a,b,c,alpha,beta,gamma,la,lb,lc,lalpha,lbeta,lgamma,rotate=0,scale=1][1]{
    
    \ifcommandkey{a}{a=\commandkey{a},}{}
    \ifcommandkey{b}{b=\commandkey{b},}{}
    \ifcommandkey{c}{c=\commandkey{c},}{}
    \ifcommandkey{alpha}{alpha=\commandkey{alpha},}{}
    \ifcommandkey{beta}{beta=\commandkey{beta},}{}
    \ifcommandkey{gamma}{gamma=\commandkey{gamma},}{}
    
    
    \def\a{\commandkey{a}}
    \def\b{\commandkey{b}}
    \def\c{\commandkey{c}}
    \def\aalpha{\commandkey{alpha}}
    \def\abeta{\commandkey{beta}}
    \def\agamma{\commandkey{gamma}}
    
    
    \def\labelalpha{\ifthenelse{\equal{90}{90}}{\cdot}{\aalpha\degree}} % OK
    %\def\labelalpha{\ifthenelse{\equal{\aalpha}{90}}{\cdot}{\aalpha\degree}} % undefined control sequence }

    
    \rotatebox{\commandkey{rotate}}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\commandkey{scale},x=1cm,y=1.0cm]
            
            \coordinate [label=left:$A$] (A) at (0,0);
            \coordinate [label=right:$B$] (B) at (\c,0);
%           \coordinate [label=above:$C$] (C) at (\Cx ,\Cy ); 
            \coordinate [label=above:$C$] (C) at (2 ,2 ); 
            \draw (A) -- node[sloped,below] {c} (B) -- node[sloped,above] {a} (C) -- node[sloped, above] {b} (A); 
            
            % angles
            \tkzMarkAngle(B,A,C)
            \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.6](B,A,C){$\labelalpha$}
            \tkzMarkAngle(C,B,A)
            \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.6](C,B,A){$\beta$}
            \tkzMarkAngle(A,C,B) 
            \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.6](A,C,B){$\gamma$}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
}


\begin{document}
\foreach \n in {1,...,2}{
    \triangleSAS[b=5,c=6,alpha=\randomint{11}{90}]
}

\end{document}
```

[image: e.g.]

## Working examples

```
\triangleSAS[b=4,c=5,alpha=45]

\triangleSAS[b=4,c=5,alpha=90]
```

[image: valid1]
[image: valid2]

Comment: Even though you linked a code, you are still asked to provide your [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). It's fine if the code is not working but at least the error would reproducible on other side to those who try to help.

Comment: Do you need to expand the argument you pass to `\fpeval` before `\fpeval` sees it?

Comment: If your code is not working, it should not have been posted as an answer in the first place. You could remove it there and put it here, extended to a MWE. And link to the other question for reference.

Comment: The MWE changed the problem... The random generation seems to work. The label defs do not work now and wrong values are used in the calculations.

Comment: Don't use `keycommand`. It's an unmaintained and buggy package.

Comment: Your original answer pointed out it didn't work, though, didn't it? I don't understand what you mean by the MWE changed the problem. Do you mean the question you answered was edited so it now asks something different and that created the problem?

Comment: I've voted to reopen this, but are you sure that's the most minimal example you can come up with?

Comment: The complete code with all packages fails to generate the random parameters in the foreach loop but draws the angles correctly. The MWE loops as expected but does not draw the angles. @egreg What do you recommend?

Comment: I reduced the code further, it looks like ```\equal{\aalpha}{90}``` fails instead of returning True/False.

Answer (score 1):

You get

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \aalpha \degree
```

and the ***last*** token is what triggers the error message.

If I add

```
\newcommand{\degree}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}
```

to the document preamble I get

[image]

and no error.

Comment: ```\degree``` seems to be added by ```\usepackage{gensymb}``` in my original script. How did you get this helpful error message? Texstudio's log is of little help when debugging.

Comment: @RootRaven You want to look in the log file, rather than at the often mosleading error message in ReXStudio.